# Ruby on Rails: localhost:3000/my_pages_dont_show_up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

## When I 'rails server' the localhost:3000 works in my browser (chrome). Here's the term:

```
tom@toms-ubuntu:~/rails_projects/routesapp$ rails s
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.16 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2016-01-12 10:56:27] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2016-01-12 10:56:27] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2013-11-22) [x86_64-linux]
[2016-01-12 10:56:27] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=4751 port=3000
```

### But for localhost:3000/page/home the browser displays:

```
NoMethodError in Page#home

Showing /home/tom/rails_projects/routesapp/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #5 raised:

undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #5):

2: <html>
3: <head>
4:   <title>Routesapp</title>
5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
6:   <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
7:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
8: </head>
```

Rails.root: /home/tom/rails_projects/routesapp

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___1001173571477850876_70164200470120'

#### I generated the html files shown in the routes.rb file below; the html files are located in app/views/page

```
Routesapp::Application.routes.draw do
  get 'page/home'

  get 'page/about'

  get 'page/contact'
```

Any ideas, comments, suggestions will be much appreciated. This is new to me. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Since you're a beginner, let me explain.

Your pages *are* showing; you've got an error:

> undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

This is a standard Ruby error - it means [undeclared variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_variable).

Since Ruby is [Object Orientated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming), it assigns "nil" values to the `NilClass` -- meaning that you end up with strange errors.

--

Normally, with debugging, you'll be able to reference the line number, and see what the issue is.

Because you've not included your view, I can only suggest that you try removing the following lines *as a test*:

```
5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
6:   <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

If these work to resolve the issue, you'll have to either populate `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` or `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css`, or use something like `nodeJS` which works to resolve errors like this.

---

You'll also be better using the following for your routes:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :pages, path: "page", only: [] do
   %w(home about contact).each do |page|
      get page
   end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Buddy take "application" on line #5 and #6 and change that "application" word to "defaults"